# Is it possible to configure a jUnit test to run only if one is online?

Tags: java, junit

Some tests make no sense to run, when i am not on the network, having access to shared resources. Running these tests offline will cause a failed test and an exception.

Is it possible for a given test to be set up in such a way that it runs only when some condition is met, for example, when there is network connectivity?

Comment: Why not just wrap the test code with "if (iAmOnTheNetwork()) then perform test else return 'passed'"?

Comment: Right, of course this can be done. With this question i wonder if jUnit allows for such (or other) conditions to be tested natively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [assumptions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html).

```
@Test public void someTestThatNeedsNetworkConnectivity() {
    assumeTrue(thereIsNetworkConnectivity());

    // ...
}
```

Comment: How does `thereIsNetworkConnectivity` work exactly? Can you post a sample please?